# Change string format (date)

Tags: python

I need to create a function that receives string `yyyy-mm-dd` and it returns the string as `dd-mm-yyyy`.

For example,

Sample input: `2020-02-10`

Expected output: `10-02-2020`

Comment: What have you tried? And where are you stuck?

Comment: As stated in an answer below you can utilise the datetime module. However, for such a simple case you could just use string slicing

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do that

```
import datetime

date = '2020-02-10'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
print(date)

>>> 10-02-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `datetime` utils. Some simple `str` manipulation will do:

```
def convert(datestr):
    return "-".join(reversed(datestr.split("-")))

convert("2020-02-10")
# '10-02-2020'
```

Some documentation:

- [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use any libraries:

```py
date  = 'yyyy-mm-dd'

def reverse_date(date):
    return '-'.join(date.split('-')[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
OldDate = '2020-02-10'
NewDate = OldDate.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

It would print the date in the form you want.